# IIS 10: Serve file with same name as directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I've just set up a IIS server, and made a simple website. I have a file called "image.aspx" and a directory called "image" and I have URL Rewrite 2.0 to not need the .aspx. When I see domain.com/image i get a no permission 403, but when I visit domain.com/image.aspx it shows. How can I make it that when you visit domain.com/image you go to domain.com/image.aspx but you are able to go to domain.com/image/file.aspx?

Comment: Before you test further? You MUST MUST MUST MUST MUST MUST clear your browser cache if you been testing. Clear your browser cache out, and then try again. This may not fix your issue, but you better learn this now, since when I first started using friendly URL's, my browser caused me to waste 3 days looking for a solution to this issue. This might not be your issue - but you BETTER check and get this issue off your list.

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution that would work for any server. Yea I've cleared the cache already

Answer (score 0):

We just check if the file with the request URL name exists then make a redirection. Moreover, the specific file under that directory is accessible too.

```
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRules" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{Request_URI}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="Https://vabqia969vm:448{request_URI}.aspx" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: So like this it would make visiting mydomain.com/image/ go to /image.aspx, and /image/test.txt go to the test.txt file?

Comment: Yes, I believe it will work. Please try it.  Feel free to let me know if it doesn't work.